# Enabling dropdown when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, forms

I've thoroughly looked for an answer but everything seems to only give me half of what I need, which is how I managed to get this started. What I'm trying to do is enable a dropdown menu when a checkbox is checked, but keep it disabled otherwise. I'm not really sure how to call the function in the tag, but then again i'm not really sure it's working.

```
function .onCheckChange() {
    if ($("#partoption2").is(':checked')) {
        $("#parttwoqty").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#partoption2").val("TRUE");
    } else {
        $("#parttwoqty").attr('disabled');
        $("#partoption2").val("FALSE");
    }
}
```

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjn3Q/1/

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked your fiddle yet, but the function name should probably be `onCheckChange` and not `.onCheckChange` (remove the period)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your fiddle, you can see the result here http://jsfiddle.net/xjn3Q/9/

```
var $checkBox = $('#partoption2'),
$select = $('#parttwoqty');


$checkBox.on('change',function(e){
if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $select.removeAttr('disabled');
}else{
   $select.attr('disabled','disabled');
}
```

});

Comment: I'm a jquery beginner, so trying to put this together with multiple sources. Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 0):

The function is correct, but the name is not. Also if you are using jQuery you shouldn't use the `onchange` attribute directly on the html tag.

In your fiddle, after including the jQuery library (1.8+) changing the JS to this works. Another thing to take into account is the using of `prop` instead of `attr`.

```
$(function(){
  $("#partoption2").on('change',function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#parttwoqty").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $("#parttwoqty").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Maybe you'll need to disable the select first so it appears disabled until the checkbox is checked,
add `$("#parttwoqty").prop('disabled', 'disabled');` after the `$(function(){` line to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code, but I will only address the ones that make this example work.

First of all, in your jsFiddle, you are using jQuery, but never load it (on the left hand side).

Secondly, since you are using jQuery, why not use the jQuery click handler, like this:

```
$('#partoption2').click(function () {
    if ($("#partoption2").is(':checked')) {
        $("#parttwoqty").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#partoption2").val("TRUE");
    } else {
        $("#parttwoqty").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#partoption2").val("FALSE");
    }
});
```